# Can I legally give someone the right to cannibalize me?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

Let say I and a friend are stranded somewhere, starving, and confident rescue will not come until we both have starved.  Realizing that it makes more sense for one to live then both of us to starve we draw straws and I draw poorly.  I give my friend permission to both kill me and eat my body to survive.

I've agreed to this plan, perhaps we even record me on video giving him permission, saying I'm of sane mind and why I made the decision etc.

My friend gets home afterwards and tells everyone how great I tasted.  For some reason people get upset and call the police.

My question, is my friend guilty of a crime?  Has my permission, and the necessity of the situation, made his actions legal?

Answer (score 5):

### [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

In Germany this is a solved matter:

- Killing on request is illegal.
- Killing someone to consume them can be *Mord*.
- Eating human remains is illegal, **even** with consent of the dead.

Why do we know this? Because [Armin Meiwes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armin_Meiwes) did exactly that: he was involved in killing Bernd-Jürgen Armando Brandes, who wanted to die, and ate the remains of him. He currently is incarcerated for life due to the conviction of Mord. This is because he was found to have killed for his own sexual gratification - one of the factors that can turn an unlawful killing/*Totschlag* ([§ 212 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__212.html)) (~manslaughter) into Mord ([§ 211 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__211.html)) (~murder 1st degree) under german law.

Consuming the remains of a human body is, as the courts found, [*Störung der Totenruhe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B6rung_der_Totenruhe) under [§ 168 StgB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__168.html) (disturbing the rest of human remains). It is not possible to consent to being eaten, as you can not give your body to anything but research or medical education legally and you have to be buried in a designated graveyard.

Comment: Would it still be a crime if he consumed the flesh while the donor was still alive?

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica the amputation would be Illegal practice of medicine. Eating the flesh would be illegal handling and mishandling of hospital-specific waste (Krankenhausspezifischer Abfall) that has to be handled according to [disposal Key  18 01 02](https://umweltschutz.charite.de/umweltschutz_informationen/abfall/abfallwegweiser/liste_e/e_abfall/#c57439) - which requires incineration of the material.

Comment: In the case you mentioned the person was convicted because his motive for killing, sexual gratification, was deemed unjustified and the person authorizing the killing was deemed innately insane if he agreed to death.  Could the rules not be different if it was found if both the person justifying the death and the person dying had sane, justifiable motives based off  necessity instead of it be all some kink taken to the extreme?

Comment: @dsollen Killing someone on their request without a factor that makes it Mord is Totschlag. German courts do **not** accept a necessity defense to kill anybody that is not actively trying to kill someone else. Also, under German law, you can not consent to being killed, as such a contract would be Sittenwidrig (against public policy)

Comment: "Mord" is often translated to English as "Murder".

Answer (score 3):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

If your friend has not guilty of an offence, it is not because of consent. Consent is vitiated when the accused intends and causes serious bodily harm to the other (*R. v. Paice*, [2005 SCC 22 at para. 18](https://canlii.ca/t/1k6m2#par18)).

However, the defence of necessity *may* be available, although the Supreme Court has never directly decided this issue. See *R. v. Latimer*, [2001 SCC 1 at para. 40](https://canlii.ca/t/523c#par40) (also surveying the law in other jurisdictions):

> The third requirement for the necessity defence is proportionality; it requires the trial judge to consider, as a question of law rather than fact, whether the harm avoided was proportionate to the harm inflicted.  It is difficult, at the conceptual level, to imagine a circumstance in which the proportionality requirement could be met for a homicide.  **We leave open, if and until it arises, the question of whether the proportionality requirement could be met in a homicide situation**.  **In England, the defence of necessity is probably not available for homicide**:  *R. v. Howe*, [1987] 1 A.C. 417 (H.L.), at pp. 453 and 429; J. Smith, *Smith & Hogan: Criminal Law* (9th ed. 1999), at pp. 249-51.  The famous case of *R. v. Dudley and Stephens* (1884), 14 Q.B.D. 273, involving cannibalism on the high seas, is often cited as establishing the unavailability of the defence of necessity for homicide, although the case is not conclusive:  see R. Card, Card Cross and Jones: Criminal Law (12th ed. 1992), at p. 532; *Smith & Hogan: Criminal Law*, *supra*, at pp. 249 and 251.  The Law Reform Commission of Canada has suggested the defence should not be available for a person who intentionally kills or seriously harms another person:  *Report on Recodifying Criminal Law* (1987), at p. 36.   **American jurisdictions are divided on this question, with a number of them denying the necessity defence for murder**:  P. H. Robinson, *Criminal Law Defenses* (1984), vol. 2, at pp. 63-65; see also *United States v. Holmes*, 26 F. Cas. 360 (C.C.E.D. Pa. 1842) (No. 15,383).  The American *Model Penal Code* proposes that the defence of necessity would be available for homicide:  American Law Institute, *Model Penal Code and Commentaries* (1985), Part I, vol. 2,  at § 3.02, pp. 14-15; see also W. R. LaFave and A. W. Scott, Jr., *Substantive Criminal Law* (1986), vol. 1, at p. 634.